# Adding a column with character data to a ffdf

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, ff, ffbase

I've tried to add a Source column to my ffdf, but can't seem to get it to work... if it was a normal df I would simply write

```
mtcars$NewCol <- "AB"
```

If I do this for the ffdf it returns an error

```
require(ff)
require(ffbase)

mtcarsff <- as.ffdf(mtcars) 
mtcars$NewCol <- "testname"

Error in `[[<-.ffdf`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "testname") : 
assigned value must be ff
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
mtcarsff$NewCol <- as.ff(
    rep(factor("AB"), times = nrow(mtcarsff))
)
```

Note that "AB" must be considered a factor, not a character.